# $\partial\bar \partial \log f=\bar \partial \partial \log\bar f$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

Assume $f$ is nonzero holomorphic function. Then is it true 
$$\partial\bar \partial \log f=\bar \partial \partial \log\bar f?$$ This is one step of construction of Fubini-Study metric in Griffith and Harris's book.

Comment: Can you list the relevant page number?

Comment: Sure, just page 30

Comment: what is $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$ ? and do you mean harmonic instead of holomorphic ?

Comment: and if $f$ is holomorphic/harmonic $\log f$ is just an holomorphic/harmonic function (locally, except at the branch cut)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since they are both zero: $\log f$ is holomorphic, so $\bar\partial \log f = 0$. $\log \bar f$ is anti-holomorphic, so $\partial \log \bar f = 0$. Thus

$$\partial \bar\partial \log f = \bar\partial \partial \log \bar f = 0.$$